# Unsibcribed observable called onNext on subscriber. How to test it

Tags: unit-testing, junit, rx-java

I've recently noticed that subscriber could receive onNext event even if it unsubscribed before due to multi-threading issues. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1590 
So i have an observable which is created with `Observable.OnSubscribe<Data>` interface `Observable.create(OnSubscribeImpl())`
That implementation just call subscriber's `onNext()` and `onCompleted()` methods according to the another asynchronous callbacks inside inner implementation. 
If there `isUncusbscribed()` check wouldn't be called before sending `onNext()` event it could lead to a bug, described above.

```
  //correct code
  if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
      subscriber.onNext(data);
  }
```

I want just to create some unit-test with `TestSubscriber` to check a situation, when subscriber.isUnsubscribed() check don't performed.

Comment: Try `Observable.fromEmitter` which handles backpressure and unsubscription correctly.

Comment: @akarnokd. Yes, it helps